# Accessing the F12 html data of mysite

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Trying to access the DOM explorer html data of a given Url.
Installed htmlAgilitypack

```
        string Deeplink = "my site";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb htmlweb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = htmlweb.Load(Deeplink);
            return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error :" + ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
```

but its not giving the exact content.

My task is to access the particular href of a content in the url

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you actually want to execute Javascript.

Comment: content is dynamic and need to access it with c# console application

Comment: Created a console application to access the DOM explorer html data.

Comment: Able to get DOM explorer data using the web browser control in form for other general sites like msn and google but not for my site https://storemanagement.windowsphone-int.com//Applications/Details/15958470?path=applications/9007199266495756